# Encoding options for byte array when hashing

Tags: c#, encoding, hash

I'm trying to write a basic hashing function accepts an input string and a salt string. Both of those strings then need to be converted to byte arrays, combined then the hash is generated.

I've dug around the Microsoft Membership for inspiration and see that they do it this way:

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(input);
byte[] array = Convert.FromBase64String(salt);
```

So what I want to ask is:

1. Is unicode the best encoding to use when converting the input string to a byte array? What about UTF-8?
2. Is a Base64String the best format to use for the salt value? If I limit to a Base64 string then essentially I always have to use a hash as a salt, is this the recommended way?

Comment: I think it depends on which encoding is your string in. :)

Comment: Well I'll be accecpting Usernames and Passwords from the web that I need to hash and Authentication values from mobile devices that I also need to hash. So presumably what encoding I use will affect these systems too?

Comment: Your salt can be whatever you want. I'm nto sure why you think Base64 means you have to use a hash as a salt. You can make a Base64 string in any number of ways... A Base64 string is in essence just a byte array that is encoded using purely ascii characters so it can be stored as a string easily.

Comment: When getting the values from the web, you get the encoding as a part of HTTP header, right? (I'm not a specialist in web programming.)